# How to determine if reported level of TLS overhead indicates a problem?

Tags: tls, performance, diagnostics, troubleshooting

Tor periodically [logs a diagnostic message with the percentage of TLS write overhead](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/164/what-is-tls-write-overhead).  How can one determine if the percentage reported is indicative of a problem with the associated tor relay?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the "TLS write overhead" percentage reported in Tor log entries?](http://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/164/what-is-the-tls-write-overhead-percentage-reported-in-tor-log-entries)

Answer (score 2):

So far it's just something that might be useful for developers to collect.  It's probably nothing that an individual user or relay operator would have to care about at this time.

It's also not even clear yet what the answer to your question really is.

As Roger explained in [What is the "TLS write overhead" percentage reported in Tor log entries?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/164/), [Ticket#7707](https://bugs.torproject.org/7707) is where some of the development discussion happens.  If you are interested in it, more details can be found there.

In short, nothing to see here, move along. :)

Comment: That is helpful, but the question is not "does this indicate a problem?" but "how can someone determine if this indicates a problem?"  If a Tor user must dig up some developer discussion in order to determine what is an acceptable rate-of-foo after finding that Tor reports its current rate-of-foo, then it is likely that this information is not useful to that user until acceptable rate is included in the Tor docs.